# Android - Contact photo from connection

Tags: android, android-contacts

When a contact has a connection, like Whatsapp or Skype, and that contact hasn't a photo, the Whatsapp or Skype photo appears.

How obtain the connection photo if the contact photo hasn't a photo?

```
public byte[] getPhoto(String contactId) {
            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(contactId));
            Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        try
        {
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                    new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    final byte[] image = c.getBlob(0);
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    return stream.toByteArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new byte[0]; 
    }
```

**SOLVED**

This method works correctly. The problem was in another part of the program. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you to all.

Comment: `the Whatsapp or Skype photo appears` where does it appear? in the contacts app? if so, then the contact does have a photo...

Comment: Yes, in the contact app. The contact hasn't a photo, but when a connection appears, appears the connection's photo, for example, the Skype user photo. By code with the API, I recover the contact photos, but the photo that appears when has only a connection photo isn't recovered by the API.

Comment: whatever photo appears in the Contacts app, should be accessible via the API, post the code you're using the get the contact photo

Answer (score 1):

First, note that a `Whatsapp` photo does not appear in your `Contacts` app, it only appears within the `Whatsapp` app, that's because it's a proprietary photo stored locally in the `Whatsapp` app and is not accessible to 3rd party apps.
I'm not sure about `Skype`, but if you do see a photo in the `Contacts` app, you should be able to access it via the API.

The code you've posted accessed the thumbnail-sized photo of the contact, it's possible that the contact has only a high-res photo and no thumbnail.

Try this code using [ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.html):

```
 public InputStream openDisplayPhoto(long photoFileId) {
     Uri displayPhotoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_URI, photoKey);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(
             displayPhotoUri, "r");
         return fd.createInputStream();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Also, this code will show you all photos stored for a contact, along with their `RawContact` ID source:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_FILE_ID, CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, CommonDataKinds.Photo.RAW_CONTACT_ID };
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId;
Cursor c = resolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
while (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {
   Long photoId = c.getLong(0);
   boolean hasPhoto = c.isNull(1);
   Long rawContactId = c.getLong(2);
   Log.d(TAG, "found photo: " + photoId + ", " + rawContactId + ", " + hasPhoto);
}
```

Comment: You are right, whatsapp doesn't appears, only appears Skype photo.

Comment: What type is Data? The query gives me  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: mimetype

Comment: And c.getLong(CommandDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_FILE_ID) doesn't compile. It will be c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_FILE_ID))?

Comment: right about the `getLong`, I've edited the code to add projection to the query, regarding `Data`, it should be `android.provider.ContactsContract.Data`